# Not Parse BBCode Between Code Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bbcode

*I have read other posts on this topic, but none of them seem to help.*

Ok, so I am coding my own BBCode parser. Now my question is how can I NOT parse the BBCode between the [code] tags? I am really not sure how I would go about this. This is my current code:

```
$('#posttextareadisplay').text($('#textareainput').val());
    var replacebbcode = $('#posttextareadisplay').html().replace(/(\[((\/?)(b|i|u|s|sup|sub|code|quote))\])/gi, '<$2>')
                                                        .replace(/(\[(rule)\])/gi, '<hr>')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((align=)(left|center|right|justify))\])/gi, '<div align="$4">')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((\/)(align))\])/gi, '</div>')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((color=#)([0-9a-fA-F]{0,}))\])/gi, '<span style="color:#$4">')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((\/)(color))\])/gi, '</span>')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((size=)(1|2|3|4|5|6))\])/gi, '<font size="$4">')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((\/)(size))\])/gi, '</font>')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((link=)([a-zA-Z0-9._:\/\\+-]{0,}))\])/gi, '<a href="$4">')
                                                        .replace(/(\[((\/)(link))\])/gi, '</a>')
                                                        .replace(/((((http|https):\/\/)(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-\.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@\/?]*)?)(\s+|$))/gi, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
    $('#posttextareadisplay').html(replacebbcode);
```

So what do I do to NOT parse the code inbetween the [code] tags? Thank You!!! :)

**P.S. I am using JS/Jquery**

Comment: Sorry for an unhelpful self-plug, but I made a `[shortcode]` library for PHP and it captures outermost matches so you'd just need to disable recursive parsing and return `[code]` content as is. You can have a look here: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode . Maybe it'll be a little bit of inspiration for you. :)

Comment: Hmm TY,but I would like to code this myself.

Comment: The correct solution is to use a real formally-structured parser. I've lost track of the number of regex-based BBCode implementations I've abused to either hack or deface a site.

Answer (score -1):

One solution would be to replace the BBCode special characters `[` and `]` with the corresponding HTML entities `&#91;` and `&#93;` so that they are not parsed later:

```
input.replace(/\[code](.*?)\[\/code]/g,function(m,a){return '<code>'+a.replace(/[[\]]/g, function(t){return '&#9'+(t=='['?'1':'3')+';';})+'</code>';})
```